# Dynamic Logging window for a webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, window

I'm building a website on which users can draw objects.

I want to build a window for logging whatever mistakes that users make

For example, the drawing rule is only circle is allowed inside a triangle. However, one user come and draw a square inside a triangle. The system still allows and perform it as the user wants. But there will be a warning message such as "only circle allowed inside a triangle" appeared in the logging window (located at the bottom of the page). Whenever the user fix the mistake, the warning in the window will be deleted.(Due to this function, I think it should be called dynamic logging window)

I'm using JavaScript with ExpressJS and dojoJS.

Can anyone tell me how to build such a window??? I'm quite new to web developing

Any help would be appreciated.

I want to build a window like this on my website
[image]

Comment: You need to track the location and span of each object that is drawn. I would suggest using a 2D collision detecting library(or a physics engine for more advanced usage) which will allow you to work with more shapes and spare you the trouble of writing your own logic for finding collisions.

Comment: @galactocalypse The question here is how to build an error logging window (like the Problems window in Eclipse, for instance. Check the image in the question).

Comment: Sorry for having missed the context entirely. I've added basic logic for the window as an answer. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking for any part of the error-detection logic or not. I haven't addressed it here.

Here's one simple way of going about this:

1. Create a fixed position div at the bottom or wherever you like. This will hold all the errors.
2. Maintain a `shapeId` for every shape added and an `errorId` for every error generated. Map the `errorId` to the list of `shapeId`s it affects. For each `errorId` add an element to the window. Set the `id` of the element as the `errorId` of the error.
3. When a shape is added/modified, iterate through all `errorId`s and modify the affected errors in the list by using their `id`.

Hope this addresses your issue.

**Update:**
If you're just going to display errors like mentioned in the question, I guess plain old Bootstrap will be enough.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9y7rcqv/)

[jSlate](http://jslate.com/pages/home) looks pretty relevant to your case. I'd suggest you take a look at the demo once.

Comment: Let me try this way

.I'll tell you and rate answer later. Thanks :D

Comment: do you know any plugins or tools helping for design the window, (as  I quite bad at designing)?  

I've searched, and got this http://terminal.jcubic.pl/.

Is this ok to use in this case?

Comment: @Ryan_Chau: A terminal emulator doesn't seem to be the kind of thing you're looking for. Check out the update I just made.

Comment: Sorry for so late response. But I have some other higher prioritized.

Ok, the window is helpful but I'm struggling with the error checking. Sorry but do you have any suggestion? 

For instance, there are conflicts inside the drawing, should i check the drawing every 3 seconds? Or is there a way to detect error immediately with the currently-used technology?

Comment: I'm not sure of what your "currently-used technology" is, but in general, it's better to handle errors/invalid inputs right when they're added. Checking for all validations every 3 seconds will be overkill.

Comment: This is a little old. however, I just want to update the situation. I added the js code to check errors and log out the error every time an object is added to the drawing. Of course, each error must be detected by an id, so that we can update the status of the error later on.

I dont know if there is a better work around. Love to hear better approaches :D